# Python For Loop - Switching from PHP

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am new to python and usually use PHP. Can someone please clear me structure of For loop for python.

```
numbers = int(x) for x in numbers
```

In PHP everything realted to For loop used to inside the body. I can't understand why methods are before for loop in python.

Comment: That's not a for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the statement is missing brackets:

```
numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers]
```

This is called a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and it is the equivalent of:

```
numbers = []
for x in numbers:
   numbers.append(int(x))
```

Note that you can also use comprehensions as [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), in which case the [] become ():

```
numbers = (int(x) for x in numbers)
```

which is the equivalent of:

```
def numbers(N):
   for x in N:
      yield int(x)
```

This means that the for loop will only execute one `yield` at the time as it is being processed. In other words, while the first example builds a list in memory, a generator returns one element at a time when executed. This is great to process large lists where you can generate one element a time without getting everything into memory (e.g. processing a file line-by-line).

So as you can see comprehensions and generator expressions are a great way to reduce the amount of code required to process lists, tuples and any other iterable.

Comment: But when there are no entries in Numbers array, how will it iterate over it?

Comment: @user4833541: Iterating over a 0-sequence iterates 0 times.

Comment: well if `numbers`  is empty to begin with, it will not execute the `int(x)` statement to begin with (looping over an empty iterable is effectively a non-operation).